# Определить разницу между 2 датами.

Tags: дата, php

Подскажите, как определить количество дней между 2 датами. Есть метод следующий:

```
$datetime1 = date_create(date('Y-m-d', $s['end']));
$datetime2 = date_create(date('Y-m-d', time()+$s['start']));
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
$intv = $interval->format('%a');
```

Но из-за бага этот метод не пригоден, так как будет выдавать постоянно 6015.
Есть ли другие альтернативные методы? Пробывал делал обычно:

```
`date('Y-m-d', $s['end'])-date('Y-m-d', time()+$s['start'])`
```

Но этот метод так же не пригоден. Заранее спасибо, долго бьюс с этой проблемой, не знаю уже что и придумать.

Comment: А почему вам не хочется перевести все в секунды и найти их разницу?

Comment: Оперировать нужно секундами и не париться, а уже после переводить в нужный формат. Это и удобно и по производительности лучше.

Comment: Могу сказать глупость, но разница в unixtime вам не подойдет? Увы точное название функции не помню.

Answer (score 5):

Для получения разницы между двумя датами, необходимо использовать нативную функцию **date_diff** (алиас такого необходимого нововведения, как класс **DateTime**).
Слово "баг" здесь неуместно, скорее всего вы делаете что-то не так.

***1 способ:***

Если переменные $s['start'], $s['end'], являются в формате timestamp, то

```
date_diff(
   date_create('@' . $s['end']), 
   date_create('@' . $s['start'])
)->format('%s');
```

Символ собаки **@**, даёт понять, что используется UNIX-время.

***2 способ:***

```
/* кол-во секунд между двумя датами */
$timediff = (int)$s['end'] - (int)$s['start'];

switch ($interval) {
    case 'y':
        $timediff = bcdiv($timediff, 31536000, 0);
        break;
    case 'w':
        $timediff = bcdiv($timediff, 604800, 0);
        break;
    case 'd':
        $timediff = bcdiv($timediff, 86400, 0);
        break;
    case 'h':
        $timediff = bcdiv($timediff, 3600, 0);
        break;
    case 'm':
        $timediff = bcdiv($timediff, 60, 0);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял массив $s выглядит примерно так:

```
    $s = array( 'start' => time()-(60*60*48), 'end' => time() );
```

Если да, то попробуйте так:

```
$datetime1 = date_create(date('Y-m-d', $s['end']));
$datetime2 = date_create(date('Y-m-d', $s['start']));
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
$intv = $interval->format('%a');
```