# Разница между двумя датами в формате

Tags: php, дата

Есть две даты, скажем **01/11/2016** и **05/11/2017**

Нужно вывести разницу между двумя датами в таком формате: **N лет, Y месяцев и X дней**. т.е. из примера должно быть - в 2016м 366 дней в 2017 365 дней +1 год, и 4 дня + 1 дней разницы в году: *1 лет 0 мес 5 дней*, как-то так. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Формат не обеспечивает определённости. Абстрактные месяцы в диапазоне, в отличие от месяцев года, имеющих строго заданное количество дней, допускают различающиеся результаты при формально одинаковой разности в днях. Но если сильно упёрлось - делайте по шагам. Посчитайте кол-во лет, прибавьте к началу, посчитайте количество месяцев, опять прибавьте, потом посчитайте количество дней.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Определить разницу между 2 датами.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/179944/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [`date_diff`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-diff.php):

```
$datetime1 = date_create('01.11.2016');
$datetime2 = date_create('05.11.2017');

$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

echo $interval->format('%y лет %m месяцев %d дней');
```

[**Пример**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5948167c3665e18790d531902aff051afef765ff)

P.S: добавляйте 1 день, если нужно учитывать конечную дату.